# underbrace issue within macros

Tags: macros, underbrace

I seem to have trouble putting an underbrace into a macro and I don't know why.
Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\URD}[1]
{
 \IfEq{#1}{}
 {\textsc{urd}}
 {\textsc{urd}\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
}
\begin{document}
$\URD{K_{\underbrace{g,\ldots,g}_7}}$
\end{document}
```

It  returns the error:

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@xs@arg@i.

when compiled. \URD works fine on simple expressions that do not contain underbrace.

What am I  to do?

Comment: `xstring` has the bad habit of fully expanding its arguments. Look for `\noexpandarg` in the manual. There are cheaper ways to test for an empty argument.

Comment: @egreg So what would be a better way to write such commands? I do this alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `\noexpandarg` or fragile commands such as `\textsc` and `\underbrace` would not survive `\IfEq`.

However there are much better ways. For this case I suggest an optional argument, rather than a mandatory one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\URD}{o}{%
  \textnormal{\scshape urd}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{(#1)}%
}

\begin{document}

$\URD$

$\URD[K_{\underbrace{g,\ldots,g}_7}]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid both `\ensuremath` and `\left\right`.

An extended version so you can choose the size of the delimiters, if you so wish. With `\URD*{...}` you get `\left` and `\right`, the last example shows why it would be bad to use them by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\URD}{soo}{%
  \textnormal{\scshape urd}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\IfValueT{#2}{\left(#2\right)}}%
    {\IfValueT{#2}{\IfValueTF{#3}%
      {\mathopen{#2(}#3\mathclose{#2)}}%
      {(#2)}%
    }}%
}

\begin{document}

$\URD$

$\URD[K_{\underbrace{g,\ldots,g}_7}]$

$\URD[\big][K_{\underbrace{g,\ldots,g}_7}]$

$\URD*[K_{\underbrace{g,\ldots,g}_7}]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But \left( and \right) will be necessary for some expressions.

Comment: @DonKreher Did you look at the output in this case with `\left` and `\right`?

Comment: @DonKreher I added an extended version with two optional arguments, also showing what you'd get with automatic `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not look at the output in this case with \left and \right, but I see your example of why it may look bad. It was a different case. It looks like I will have to learn xparse.  It seems I discover a new package to learn every day. And I have been at this since the beginning.

Comment: @DonKreher The current count of subdirectories of the `.../tex/latex` directory is 2352, it takes more than six years to learn a package a day. `;-)`

Comment: And ... I just finished writing one ... but still cleaning it up before submission.